# Unable to print Quotations and Sale Orders from portal user

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I faced a slight problem In Portal : portal user can not print Quotations and Sale Orders reports.

How to Reproduce :

```
Login as portal user
Go to Portal menu
Chose any Quotation or Sale Order and try to print this.
```

Then I see error

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://0.0.0.0:8069" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

So, the only way to solve it I see is monkeyPatching runtime with sudo() at the moment we are accessing report. But I don't know how to do it the right way. I will be thankful for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by downloading MS fonts and reload it on my production server. This bug can cause because reports building dynamically and if Sale Order or Quotation have any specific symbol it will throw error in Chrome or start longpooling in Firefox